# Angular Template in MVC Core does not install the npm packages

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, templates

I have created a new applicationWeb Core + Angular template in VS 2017. But in the npm nodes all angular files are marked as not installed. What should I do?
Here is  screenshot[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt in the solution directory and type the command:

```
npm install
```

Note: you must have node.js installed ([NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/))